# Compare array values in php and update table

Tags: php, arrays, html, mysqli

I have two arrays from SQL select statements in php $resultA and $resultB. The array is built with mysqli_fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC).  I want to compare the grades for each subject and either get an improved, decreased, or stayed the same result.  What is the best practice to compare these values in the array and add the results on to the end of the array in new fields (i.e. ReadingPerformance, MathPerformance, SciencePerformance, & AttendancePerformance) so they can be accessed to be displayed in a table

```
Array ( [mID] => 1 [mFirst] => Mike [mLast] => Davis [mNumber] => 123456789 [mSchool] => SSAS [mGrade] => 8 [gID] => 0 [gYear] => 2017 [gReading] => A [gMath] => A [gScience] => B [gSemester] => Q1 [gDaysAbsent] => 1 ) 
Array ( [mID] => 1 [mFirst] => Mike [mLast] => Davis [mNumber] => 123456789 [mSchool] => SSAS [mGrade] => 8 [gID] => 1 [gYear] => 2017 [gReading] => B [gMath] => B [gScience] => A [gSemester] => Q2 [gDaysAbsent] => 4 )
```

Final Table Headers

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: mysqli_fetch_array() is deprecated in PHP7, consider using the mysqli class with fetch_assoc()

I presume you have ordered your query, probably by mID, which will make this way easier.
My suggestion is that you create an array where you collect your data and then loop through it to create the table (I'll write it out sequentially, but you should consider slicing it up into class methods). Note: this is untested.

```
// execute the query
$result = mysqli_query($handler, $query);

// create a stack to collect the data
$data = array();

// the table header, will also be used to store values in order
$metaData = array(
    'mID' => 'MemberID(system)',
    'mFirst' => 'First Name',
    // other meta data (make sure you use the field names)...
);

$grades = array(
    'gReading' => 'Reading',
    'gMath' => 'Math',
    'gScience' => 'Science',
    'gDaysAbsent' => 'Absent'
);

// create a table header
$tableHeader = $metaData;
// create 3 fields for each subject
foreach ($grades as $fieldname => $headline) {
    $tableHeader[$fieldname . 'Q2'] = $headline . ' Q2';
    $tableHeader[$fieldname . 'Q1'] = $headline . ' Q1';
    $tableHeader[$fieldname . 'Performance'] = $headline . ' Performance';
}

// read each row of the result
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    // we haven't handled this user before
    if (!array_key_exists($row['mID'], $data)) {
        // create a row with the meta data
        $tableRow = array();
        foreach ($metaData as $fieldname => $headline) {
            $tableRow[$fieldname] = $row[$fieldname];
        }
    } else {
        // fetch this users previous data
        $tableRow = $data[$row['mID']];
    }
    // populate the grades for this quarter and calculate the performance
    foreach ($grades as $gradename => $headline) {
        // f.ex. gReadingQ1
        $tableRow[$gradename . $row['gSemester']] = $row[$gradename];
        // calculate the performance
        if ($tableRow[$gradename . 'Q1'] && $tableRow[$gradename . 'Q2']) {
            // TODO: do some magic here
            // f.ex. calculate the number of the letter in the alphabet and get the average
            $tableRow[$gradename . 'Performance'] = 'SOMETHING';
        }
    }
    // store the row
    $data[$row['mID']] = $tableRow;
}

// TODO: create the table in whatever format you want
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Covers most of it, but I have two arrays from two queries that contain the data.  Do this for each array and then process both to a third array?

Comment: Why do you have two queries? The results look like they come from the same table. If that's the case you should make your query more generic (f.ex. `semester IN ("Q1", "Q2")` to avoid hitting the DB too often.
If you really need to do two queries, just put the results in an array and instead of the while loop to fetch the rows do a foreach over your result stack.